# python looping through 2 lists skipping similar elements

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 identical lists
a = [a1,a2,a3]
b = [a1,a2,a3]
What is a most effective way to iterate over these 2 list simultaneously while i am interesting only in combination of different elements from both lists despite order, i.e a1a2 and a1a3. Combinations a1a1, a2a2, a3a3, a2a1, a3a1 i am interesting to skip, but interesting keep iterators values avaliable.

Want to re phrase questions:
interesting in possible combinations of 2 elements from list a = [a1,a2,a3]

Comment: Use `itertools.product`, perhaps, with an `if left == right: continue` to skip those where they're both the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can't it be as simple as `itertools.combination(a,2)` as both the list are identical and combination would automatically remove the duplicate ones

Comment: @armak you could do it like that, but that doesn't *"iterate over these 2 list simultaneously"*. It depends what the OP's actually trying to achieve, which isn't entirely clear - if the two lists are *always* identical, it's not obvious why they have two to start with.

Comment: What is the point of having 2 identical lists? Why not just have 1 list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations),

```
from itertools import combinations
for i in combinations(['a1','a2','a3'],2):
    print i
```

Comment: with small modification, worked. Thank you @Rahul K P

Answer (score 0):

**List comprehensions!**

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['1', '2', '3']

c = [i + j for i in a for j in b if j != i]
print(c)  # prints -> ['12', '13', '21', '23', '31', '32']
```

> EDIT

if you consider `a1a2` and `a2a1` to be duplicates you can use some clever slicing to skip them like so:

```
c = [ia + ib for i, ia in enumerate(a) for ib in a[i+1:]]
print(c)  # prints -> ['12', '13', '23']
```

As you might notice, list `b` is not used in the second one.

Comment: in this case i am not interested in '21','31','32' since it is repeating elements in combinations

Comment: @Felix Oh, sorry i missed that. the code is now updated.